# how to connect google suit domain with WordPress?

Tags: wordpress

I bought the domain and I was trying to connect with WordPress. I searched on google, but could not sort out. Can anybody tell me the procedure for this?

Comment: you need to add "A record" of the server where the files are hosted to the google domain, thats it...

Comment: @charankumar can you provide some links where I can follow step by step?

Comment: https://support.office.com/en-us/article/create-dns-records-when-your-domain-is-managed-by-google-enom-3c490fbf-7833-4e43-be34-ed0dc3cce5e3 looks like it should walk you through it

Comment: @Edunikki I did successfully but, my question is how do I connect my G-suit domain with WordPress.

Comment: @wardahamk You need to either have your wordpress site hosted on a server or to redirect your domain to your wordpress.com site. If you have a hosted site it will have an ip address that you link the domain and site together using. If you are on wordpress.com then take a look at https://en.support.wordpress.com/domains/map-existing-domain/

Comment: @Edunikki I understand! I own a domain. I entered the domain in WordPress and authorized by the code. After this, it says: domain is waiting for an approval. Couldn't I get this?

Comment: @wardahamk where is your wordpress site hosted? with wordpress? or a different host?

Comment: @EdunikkiI bought the plan for WordPress. and the domain is from go daddy.